# Sum of squares and primes

Tags: number-theory, sums-of-squares

Let $S$ be the set of the integers that can be represented as the sum of two squares.
$S={0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 13, 16, 17, 18, 20, 25, 26, 29, 32, ...}$.
I have made this hypothesis: If an integer is in set $S$ but it can be represented as a sum of squares with two different ways, then this number is not prime.
I have found Fermat's theorem on sums of two squares but I have not a proper proof on that.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to proof this theorem of Fermat using Gaussian Integers? Considering the prime elements in the Gaussian integers should give you an answer. Also when you say two different ways, you only consider $n=a^2+b^2, a,b \in \mathbb{N}$, right?

Comment: see Brillhart  http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Brillhart_Euler_factoring_2009.pdf

Comment: @includeCMath Yes, all the numbers are natural.